# hasMany vs having a collection of an object in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a difference between using hasMany

```
static hasMany = [objects:Object]
```

and adding a collection of object

```
Set objects
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a difference between using:

`static hasMany = [objects:Object]` and `List objects`

`static hasMany = [objects:Object]` is stored in a java set there you cannot have duplicate objects.  Furthermore, the objects will not be in order of insertion.

`List objects` is a typical java list which will allow duplicates as well as be able to maintain order.

I believe there are more differences but I am just posting the differences I am aware of.